# Neo4j - Gremlin - How to sort results returned by .groupCount.cap()

Tags: sorting, neo4j, gremlin

I have one problem.
this query:

```
g.V.filter{it.type == 'user'}.outE.filter{it.label == 'follow'}.outV.groupCount().cap()
```

return HashMap

```
{v[1]=1, v[138]=3, v[140]=3, v[6]=1, v[203]=1, v[619]=7, v[131]=1, v[10]=4, v[192]=1, ...}
```

how to order that? 
output need to be 
v[619]=7,  v[10]=4,, v[138]=3, v[140]=3, ...

```
g.V.filter{it.type == 'user'}.outE.filter{it.label == 'follow'}.outV.groupCount().cap().sort{-it.value} not working
```

thanx

Comment: That sorting is a normal Groovy construct, so you should be able to figure it out using plain Groovy, e.g. http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#sort(java.util.Comparator) ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to next() the map out of the cap().  Here's an example from the gremlin terminal:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.in.groupCount.cap().sort{-it.value}
==>{v[1]=3, v[6]=1, v[4]=2}
gremlin> g.V.in.groupCount.cap().next().sort{-it.value}
==>v[1]=3
==>v[4]=2
==>v[6]=1
```